# PHP MySQL Alternative for 1 value

Tags: php, date, persistence, text-files

I need to save 1 date value but I dont want to make a whole database for it. I need the date for a countdown and the date needs to be changeable via a form on the site.

Any alternatives? I was thinking about a .txt file with the date but i couldnt find a proper guide on writing to a txt with php

thanks in advance

Comment: [file_put_contents()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) & [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Comment: How persistent do you want this to be?

Comment: I need this date to be saved somewhere, and everyone with access to the form should be able to update it. So the date needs to exist forever. No cookies here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by "HamZa DzCyberDeV":

```
    // to save it
    $date = "2013-02-08 14:28";
    file_put_contents("countdownFileName.txt", $date);
    // to open it
    $countdown = file_get_contents("countdownFileName.txt");
```

(you do need access to write that file from php)